# Regex multiple conditions

Tags: regex

I have a string containing a URL like `https://xxxx.yyyy.com/en`.

How can I make a regex that verifies that **both** of these conditions are met?

- The URL does not contain `xxxx`.
- The URL *does* contain either `/en$` or `/en/`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use

```
/^(?!.*xxxx).*\/en(?:$|\/)/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rKlKOn/2)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.*xxxx)` - there can't be `xxxx` after any 0+ chars other than line break chars
- `.*` - any 0 or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `\/en` - `/en` substring
- `(?:$|\/)` - end of string or `/`

So, if you want to replace `xxxx` with more than one term, use

```
/^(?!.*(?:stage|acc)).*\/en(?:$|\/)/
```

Note that you may force the engine to match them as whole words if you add word boundaries:

```
/^(?!.*\b(?:stage|acc)\b).*\/en(?:$|\/)/
```

If you need a full string match, add `.*` at the end of the pattern.

Comment: Thanks! That solved the problem.
Looks like I have a bit more studying to do.

Comment: @AhmadBamieh There are no loops here, only 1 lookahead. `(?:$|\/)` is not equal to `\/?$`, as the latter [won't find `en/` in `.../en/more`](https://regex101.com/r/ozgsCr/1)

Comment: @AhmadBamieh: I think you have not noticed that the lookahead I am using is *anchored* at the start of the string. The check is only made **once** at the start of the string. Your *you need to keep going in and out the lookahead* statement is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Using only lookarounds:

`^(?!.*xxxx)(?=.*\/en(?:$|\/)).*`

```
^             // start of line
(?!.*xxxx)    // look ahead and don't match anything then 'xxxx'
(?=           // look ahead and match
.*\/en        // anything then '/en'
(?:$|\/)      // end of line OR a slash
)             // end of look ahead
.*            // match all (can be omitted if testing lines)
```

- Flags: global, multiline
- Steps: 188
- [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3YZYYF/5)

Comment: This regex [will not match `en/` not at the end of the string](https://regex101.com/r/3YZYYF/2). Besides, there is no need for the second lookahead, you may put that `.*en\/?$` instead of `.*` at the end, make it a consuming pattern - `^(?!.*xxxx.*).*en\/?$`. Still, it won't do what OP needs in all the scenarios.

Comment: Thanks. I changed it to allow `en/foo`. I'm practicing lookarounds to test how far I can go with it.

Comment: :) Yes, now it is just like my regex, but matches the text after `en/` in the lookahead. Basically the same, but complicated 1 step more since the consuming part is moved to the second lookahead. Note that in your pattern, `en` is not preceded with `/` and can thus be matched in `mena/`

Comment: Good catch. Updated.