# How to identify a set of nearly-identical sentences while excluding sentences containing a specified word?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to create a regex that will identify sentences that are structured as follows: The sentence begins with "I require", followed by any number of random words; the sentences ends with "to disclose the information."  If the sentence contains the word "refuse", the regex rejects the sentence as not fitting the pattern.

When applied to the following sentences, this is how the regex will return:

- I require the creepy caterpillar to disclose the information. --TRUE
- I require the giant bug to refuse to disclose the information. --FALSE
- I require the dusty moth to disclose the information. --TRUE
- You must not refuse. --FALSE

Here's what I have tried:

I can get 3 out of the 4 example sentences correct by writing `^(?:(?!refuse)(.))+$`

I can get 2 out of the 4 example sentences correct by writing `I require [\s\w]+ to disclose the information.`

I can get 2 of the 4 example sentences correct by writing `^(?:(?!refuse)(I require [\s\w]+ to disclose the information.))$`

Edit: This question differs from the one at [Regex Multiple Conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45877266/regex-multiple-conditions) because that question is dealing with two relatively simple truth conditions; this question involves a complex truth condition in the form of a sentence with variables in the middle of it.  The answer at at [Regex Multiple Conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45877266/regex-multiple-conditions) however could be considered a duplicate because it also contains the piece of information I was missing, which is: the negative lookahead needed a wildcard.

Comment: Why not just... use two regexes, one to check for the structure and one to check for the banned word?

Comment: @Karl, keep in mind that askers may have varied reasons for asking a question. It's not always about finding the most practical solution to a problem. Often it is just curiosity about how one can solve a problem in a particular way. I'm sure you've seen many answers that present regular expressions that are so complex and convoluted that no one in their right mind would use them in practice. Yet such answers may have exceptional educational value.

Comment: Aside from that, this is clearly a duplicate; the question is about how to check two separate conditions at a specific point in the regex. There's specific technique for that (even if it may or may not be the best thing to do in individual circumstances; my comment had nothing to do with my closure decision); it works the same way regardless of the complexity of the conditions (use lookahead for one of them); and it's explained by the linked duplicate.

Comment: I'm fully in support of deleting duplicates - they distract people who were searching for the more basic question posed at 'Regex Multiple Conditions'.  But I'm also in support of retaining variants of a question (in this case, the variant represented by including [\s\w]+) because the variant stopped me from recognizing the solution in 'Regex Multiple Conditions'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
r'^(?!.*\brefuse\b)I require\b[\w\s]*\bto disclose the information\.$'
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rpcpdB/1)

---

This regular expression can be broken down as follows.

```
^                                Match beginning of string
(?!                              Begin positive lookahead
  .*                             Match zero or more characters other
                                 than line terminators
  \brefuse\b                     Match literal surriounded by word boundaries
)                                End negative lookahead
I require\b                      Match literal followed by word boundary
[\w\s]*                          Match zero or more word characters or
                                 whitespace characters
\bto disclose the information\.  Match literal preceded by word boundary
$                                Match end of string
```

Comment: Hi Cary, thank you very much - I've been trying to figure out how to do this for days.

Comment: oymonk, I'm glad to be of help.